# MySql Select rows based on other rows

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

This is my current result from `MySQL` table `tbl_msresponse`

```
MobileNo         Time                     Status
xxxxx69333       2019-09-15 13:11:54      FAILED 
xxxxx69333       2019-09-15 14:12:16      FAILED
xxxxx69333       2019-09-15 14:21:34      DELIVERED **<- this row required**
xxxxx88779       2019-09-15 13:11:54      FAILED **<- this row required**
xxxxx76555       2019-09-15 14:12:16      FAILED
xxxxx76555       2019-09-15 14:21:34      DELIVERED **<- this row required**
```

From the above I want

```
 MobileNo        Time                     Status
 xxxxx69333      2019-09-15 14:21:34      DELIVERED 
 xxxxx88779      2019-09-15 13:11:54      FAILED 
 xxxxx76555      2019-09-15 14:21:34      DELIVERED
```

So, now I want only `DELIVERED` row. If there is no `DELIVERED` row, I want show only last `FAILED` row of `MobileNo` based on `Time` col. How can I achieve this in `MySQL`?

Comment: Have you tried anything till now ?

Comment: 'no success row' define success please.

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry, it is FAILED or DELIVERED. Will update my question

Comment: @SudhirOjha Sorry, I am just selection `select * from tbl_msresponse` only, now I wan t filter those records which I dont know how to :(

Comment: @Learner i think you have to create a store procedure for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit for take just 1 result, if you want to last you need to use DESC keyword otherwise ASC you can write like this:

```
Select * from table_name where Status="Delivered" or Status = Select status from table_name where Status="Failed" order by Time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please help me

Comment: Got answer here : https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group

Answer (score 0):

If you with to use stored procedure, then here is my solution using stored procedure. Actually you can write `if/else` condition inside stored procedure. The condition basically check if any row exists with `DELIVERED` status then return all rows else return `FAILED` status row order by Time and limit is 1.

Here is procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure my_procedure()
begin
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_response where status='DELIVERED')
    THEN
        SELECT * from tbl_msresponse WHERE Status='FAILED' order by Time DESC LIMIT 1;
    ELSE
        SELECT * from tbl_msresponse WHERE Status='DELIVERED';
    END IF;
end //
DELIMITER;
```

And you can call this procedure like:

```
call my_procedure();
```

Comment: Can I use with multiple mobile numbers ?

Comment: Yes you can. No restriction on it.

Comment: It is showing either DELIVERED or FAILED if I use multiple numbers. I want want both number's status like `94444xxx-delivered`, `9888xxx-failed`, `9666xxx-delivered` like in a single query

Comment: Updated my question. I want like this result

Comment: Got answer here : https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group

Answer (score 0):

Assuming status is binary (ie failed or delivered) then discussion of status is irrelevant, all you need is the most recent entry by mobileno

```
select t.*
from t 
where time = (select max(time) from t t1 where t1.mobileno = t.mobileno);

+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| MobileNo | Time                | Status    |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+
|    69333 | 2019-09-15 14:21:34 | DELIVERED |
|    88779 | 2019-09-15 13:11:54 | FAILED    |
|    76555 | 2019-09-15 14:21:34 | DELIVERED |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working, but very slow. Taking 4sec for a row. I have more than 5000 rows to filter from. Any optimization?

Comment: 4 secs a row is unexpectedly slow. Can you add your table definition please and try adding indexe(s) on mobileno and time.

Comment: OK, will try and update you. Thanks

Comment: Got answer here : https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group